# sbt publish generates html instead of class

Tags: scala, sbt, gitlab-ci

I have a scala library that i'm packaging with sbt, in my local bash, i can publish it succesfully to nexus, but when i use gitlab ci/cd with same command (sbt publish) the generated jar contains only html files:
here's my build.sbt:

```
organization := "com.example"
name := "liblib"
version := "1.0"

publishTo := Some("nexus" at "nexus/repo")

credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials")
```

and my gitlab.ci

```
package:
  stage: build
  image: scala-sbt:8u312_1.5.5_2.12.15
  script:
    # Build
    - sbt clean test:compile
    # Test
    - sbt coverage test
    - sbt coverageReport
    - mv target target-for-sonar
    # Package
    - sbt clean compile package
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_JOB_NAME artifacts from $CI_PROJECT_NAME on $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
    paths:
      - target
      - target-for-sonar
    expire_in: 1 week

publish:
  stage: publish
  image: scala-sbt:8u312_1.5.5_2.12.15
  script:
    - sbt publish
  rules:
    - when: manual
```

Comment: Locally, you are surely running sbt from the right directory, on GitLab, since you are setting CI yourself, there is a chance that directories are wrong - sbt would happily run in an empty directory, and then compile/package/publish would not create any class files. It is not the only possible explanation but I would check it first by printing out the current directory in CI job, print the files after sbt finishes, etc. This should help figuring out what goes wrong.

Comment: After check, sbt commands are done on the right folder and all.
Couldnt know the root cause, but i managed to make it work, by adding deleting manually the target
`before_script: - rm -rf target`
and then sbt publish

Comment: It sounds like problem with sbt caching. Perhaps your environment reused target but had only some of it retrived from cache, sbt considered classes to be built and only added "missing" html, and then packed everything to JAR "believing" classes are there. Maybe you could change your env to not reuse previous sbt run, especially since you are just removing `target`, so getting things from cache just to delete them seem redundant.